# is it possible to add times?

Tags: java

i want to Add two times like this...

```
String t1="04:10 PM";
String t2="04:20 PM";
```

Comment: pIs share the code so far that you have attempted for the question

Comment: What are you expectations?  Would that be 8:30?

Comment: String sfajar = ajarr.getText().toString();
                String zohar = zohar.getText().toString();
                String asar = Asar.getText().toString();
                String maghrib = Maghrib.getText().toString();
                String Eshaa = Esha.getText().toString();       
                String endTime="25:00";   here i want to add the string endtime with al these times get from the users and store anto databse..

Comment: But what are your expectations?  Adding 410 to 420 "should" give a time of 830 the next day, assuming you're taking about the number of seconds from midnight for each value.  The problem is, I don't think you really understand what it is you're asking.  Remember, 4pm is actually 16 hours past midnight

Comment: @MadProgrammer Actually i m developing auto silencer app for that i get times from the user for the phone silent now i want to add some gap time from the app for the phone unsilent atumatically after some time like after 20 min..

Comment: @wisalkhan Ok, so you want to add some time to a time, not add them together?!

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes Exactly ..

Answer (score 1):

> Actually i m developing auto silencer app for that i get times from the user for the phone silent now i want to add some gap time from the app for the phone unsilent atumatically after some time like after 20 min..

Okay, so you want to "add" time to a pre-existing time value, not "add two times together", which is a whole other problem (of a stack of can of worms)

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "04:10 pm";

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.UK);
        LocalTime lt1 = LocalTime.parse(value, formatter);
        lt1 = lt1.plusMinutes(20);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(lt1));
    }
}
```

Something like the above will print `04:30 pm`, although, I'd only use the formatted result for printing, and keep making use of the `LocalTime` value.

Another issue might be, what happens if the time rolls over to the next day?  You could use something like `LocalDateTime ldt = lt1.atDate(LocalDate.now());` to get a instance of `LocalDateTime`, which might be more suitable, but then I'd be making sure that ALL you dealings are using `LocalDateTime` instead, it'd just make it simpler.

Take a look at the [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) trail for more details.

Comment: Error..    Text '04:10 pm' could not be parsed at index 6

Comment: I had issues with `PM`, so you might need to look at the underlying locale

Comment: @wisalkhan I updated the example to make use of `Locale.UK` directly

Comment: yess now its work..tnks bro..

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that with strings since you'll just get "04:10 PM04:20 PM". You could use **SimpleDateFormat** to add times.

For example,

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date d1 = df.parse("04:10 PM");
Date d2 = df.parse("04:20 PM");
long total = d1.getTime() + d2.getTime();
```

You could also use **Calendar**.

Comment: Or, you could move to the currently recommend APIs and leave behind, what has effective become deprecated APIs, and use the [Date/Time APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html)

Comment: Oh, and simply adding times can be rather problematic, as it doesn't take into all the edge cases that associated with dealing with date/time

Comment: it give me ans like this 2640000??

Comment: @wisalkhan , thats what you asked for. you want to add the time together, so he use getTime() to convert it to long so you can add it

Comment: let me put it in a way that even you can understand. Date d1 = df.parse(fajar); Date d2 = df.parse(gapeTime); long totalTime = d1.getTime() + d2.getTime(); if you do not want it in long, use Instant where String totalStr = Instant.ofEpochMilli(totalTime).toString()

Comment: yess Exactly ...got it tnks bro..